# How to add many elements to database with MODX-processor

Tags: php, modx-revolution

I have a file-uploading-processor with array output. How I can add this array to database?

That's my processor's code:

```
class ModCLJsonUploadProcessor extends modProcessor {
    public $languageTopics = ['modcl'];

    public function process() {
        $file = fopen($_FILES['json-file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        $json = fread($file, $_FILES['json-file']['size']);
        $objs = json_decode($json);
        $english = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($objs); $i++) {
            $english[$i] = $objs[$i]->{'name'};
        }

        return $this->success($english);
    }
}

return 'ModCLJsonUploadProcessor';
```

I tried to use the native modObjectCreateProcessor, but it does not support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save items into the database using a processor, the best practice would be to create a schema and save the given data as objects in the database. This allows you to then later retreive the items (objects) in other processors or snippets using xPDO.

For a basic explenation/how to on creating a schema and interacting with the custom objects have a look at the "Developing an extra in MODX Revolution" doc [here](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/case-studies-and-tutorials/developing-an-extra-in-modx-revolution)